# Non-type template argument, from constant function argument?

Tags: c++, templates, non-type-template-parameter

I'm experimenting with C++ templates, and a kind of heterogenous type-safe map. Keys go with specific types. An example use would be something like a CSS stylesheet. I've got it to where I can things write:

```cpp
styles.set<StyleKey::fontFamily>("Helvetica");
styles.set<StyleKey::fontSize>(23.0);
```

That type checks as desired; it won't compile calls where the key does not match it's intended value type.
But I'm wondering if there's also a way to write it like this:

```cpp
styles.set(StyleKey::fontFamily, "Helvetica");
styles.set(StyleKey::fontSize, 23.0);
```

... and have it deduce the same thing, because the first argument is a constant.

Here's my flailing attempt, pasted below and on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGe1wAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxCAAnACspAAOqAqETgwe3r56KWmOAkEh4SxRMQm2mPYFDEIETMQEWT5%2BXJXVGXUNBEVhkdFxiQr1jc05bcPdvSVlgwCUtqhexMjsHCYaAILmAMzByN5YANQmO25Ow8SYrKfYG9tmewwHXsenbpfBwLf3915pRiOzDYCiSTFWR2G6FOVi290uXgcRzQtBIJwA7LDNkcjlRUUwCEcyMBSBEYb90QARclbVIEK6sE5mABsqCS0QJaPe7wgdIZLCZrK8BFIyIEwzFqOIguQcwxWJxVwIywYRyWhO5ZyZZhM8SsZjMJzO72RADppZq3EcwLwbUa3CbkKbgPaTTbSHbLWaIq6teYdfFqQaadsqb8tgB6CNHADieAAbpgFJDUGwCAgvkd0wSjgB3Ja0dBHBBMRNZgCe7IUIEh9K%2BorxqAJopRJFFEVQnnujB8yIMCmTdXL9AA0phy/L7jj%2BIIAGKsOgT06Uo5tXGyIR4ABemAbsiybaO8bwaQi9Ap1J2WPuBEwLCSBlv9qHo/HRwA1uOflsEUix%2BWADUxC8TAABVK0wSc4ThMMr3DTZf0JF9MAAWSYJIQxvO8HwJSDNTuH96URQl/yA7wwIg95kP/EAQBnAh5xYRdbig7EK3ZLAqFrYhM3jYDMAAfQISi4K2HFJkcZAj1QPAiyUAgIGQtCkiOAAqBQWFFPjyKEiCj34uZMNgrFb3vR88ONHYCIQoi/3HMiQPA9kqOE19y1o%2BjNx3FiTExKd2MwTjcXxQltJA3TnNEtiJLwKT4xkuTMAUpT0LUjStP4iLILCzBDKvHEL0wwjiGIo4UpU3yFW4zN6MYxcjRXf0mqi6cQvXQQvIslcpBDHFW2leiDwtHYV36yqNFICaNF8y8qo7TwjxPPAzy6rMSswIq2NMnCnxc4dMH/D8vys/z4tkyEkogYT2WBSDSP4pyNrOT9y1uWicqy/TyLlSr/L69VfStf15O1QGjggYICDmF6wf9L6QJrOGvRysHXFoXqcSOe7yMe94XrekB5KujMFAy76MZm%2BCcW28zn1cg633xk6xOk875LMRT6cOl6zFFa7GFYO77IekS3CZ7B3sy/n4dy1jMdrAlYoEpgB2iBSYeXZcjvLMw8qq/7hVhg0QaRyyrQhwRobfL04ZyxGDTBlGvTRimwxg2b4LOotscc0XqPHDzZDq2hXqs2iifKtLNOqwFLh%2BvyWY0gBaW5aoXEOGu4ozqS2L2seFnG/a5gO6I3bcnolwnLsj9To8bHMFC3eOquT1Oy53TPG%2Bzz2EqOJIeMECA0AYCVI/MZkNOb/y0ENm2DXo3F04ne3DS9DTTTTpiM9Rhh0HRlqxVns3tQXtIO5xFewfXzzy/l53d/3qqZ41Y//X6%2BXMcvteWA3/dPDRAqx8XYH2fkbMwx5Tz0A/l/Y%2B68IHLSgXfIBD8YQFXdvBSGRwWBMGCBAKe0E2JRljE2WgIB/JRnIdGSOwx9oKAxkQmh9A6F6k3sxQMmd/QAAkqiJkkkwZqVUGH02YRYG%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%2BZDKopKpkRGIDKjwWBOAQrrCwF1tK8RMGAAoACeBMC5iVTdD1MgOqiHEFIUN8glBqFJboNovLjDWGsPoZa1ZIALDZDUasHAjhJwAOpiFoHm/NJr6RMDzRxQwkk81QmXKYIFlgzAaCOBSqoZqaguF3mMVopBAjBD6KUAYbQ8jpAED23IqQx0MGmP0GIEx20GoEF0UYngWh6DsB2zoIwegDpmMO2wO6J0TB3bOod86FgKCWCsdgbR6SYDWDwN5nBPmkG%2Bb8/5HBVAYuZEnZkkg%2ByGBdFIGRMjwaAv1DYI4uBCBckeGuDwJT6AWng3MXg1KtBzAWAga4WAYh4MJRwYlpB3UIrfaSz9FKQBUuhQselTL1RJGFOQFw%2BAiA8XQHoTy4bb3SHoooFQ6gdXxtIKM9CHrn0fJJTqz9SrhRMcJKgLi37f3/sA4CEDiKW0QEQ6y5DTIcVochbR2F8KJrvOI6Ria77eCUdsNR4zNKsOkDhZIWIpp8U7A0GYSQXAf0YviMyLgCbOA7Gkx%2B8ljnMOSbMOF2zkWMMwtIImUVGQQCSCAA%3D%3D). The `set2` template does not work.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

struct color {
  float r,g,b;
};
ostream &operator <<(ostream &out, const color &c) {
  return out << "[" << c.r << ',' << c.g << ',' << c.b << "]";
}

// Gives something that would have types: string, float, color, bool
enum class StyleKey {
  fontFamily = 1, fontSize, fontColor, visible
};

template <StyleKey key>
struct KeyValueType {

};

struct StyleMap;

template <>
struct KeyValueType<StyleKey::fontFamily> {
  typedef string value_type;
  static void set(StyleMap *sm, value_type value);
};
template <>
struct KeyValueType<StyleKey::fontSize> {
  typedef float value_type;
  static void set(StyleMap *sm, value_type value);  
};

struct StyleMap {
  string fontFamily = "";
  float fontSize = 14;
  color fontColor = color{0,0,0};
  bool visible = true;

  template <StyleKey key>
  void set(typename KeyValueType<key>::value_type value) {
    cout << "set " << (int)key << " value: " << value << endl;
    KeyValueType<key>::set(this, value);
  }

  template <StyleKey key>
  void set2(StyleKey key2, typename KeyValueType<key>::value_type value) {
    static_assert(key == key2);
    cout << "set " << (int)key << " value: " << value << endl;
  }
};

void KeyValueType<StyleKey::fontFamily>::set(StyleMap *sm, string str) {
  sm->fontFamily = str;
}
void KeyValueType<StyleKey::fontSize>::set(StyleMap *sm, float sz) {
  sm->fontSize = sz;
}

void print(const StyleMap &sm) {
  cout << "font family : " << sm.fontFamily  << endl;
  cout << "font size   : " << sm.fontSize    << endl;
  cout << "color       : " << sm.fontColor   << endl;
  cout << "visible     : " << sm.visible     << endl;  
}

int main() {

  // Goal:
  //
  // StyleMap styles;
  // styles[fontFamily] = "Helvetica";
  // styles[fontSize] = 15.0;
  // string fam = styles[fontFamily]
  // float sz   = styles[fontSize];
  
  StyleMap styles;

  // This works!
  styles.set<StyleKey::fontFamily>("Helvetica");
  styles.set<StyleKey::fontSize>(23.0);

  // This won't compile, as desired
  // styles.set<StyleKey::fontFamily>(20);

  // But can we write it like this?
  // styles.set2(StyleKey::fontFamily, "Helvetica");
  // styles.set2(StyleKey::fontSize, 23.0);  

  print(styles);
}
```

Comment: I can't think of anything better than a macro, like `#define set2(key, val) set<key>(val)` I suspect this cure is worse than the disease. It's relatively easy to implement your desired syntax if it's OK to detect the type mismatch at runtime; but I don't see a way to have it fail at compile time.

Comment: Function parameters are never constexpr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do SFINAE or specialization on function parameters, only template parameters.  That means this can't work using your current approach.

What you could do is change your `StyleKey`s from being `enum` values to being empty tag structs with different types.  Then you could specialize `KeyValueType` on each of those types and pass an object of one of those types to `StyleMap::set`.  It can then use the type of that object to deduce the correct `KeyValueType` specialization to dispatch to.

```
namespace StyleKey {
  static constexpr inline struct FontFamily {} fontFamily;
  static constexpr inline struct FontSize {} fontSize;
};

template <typename KeyType>
struct KeyValueType {};

struct StyleMap;

template <>
struct KeyValueType<StyleKey::FontFamily> {
  using value_type = std::string;
  static void set(StyleMap *sm, value_type value);
};
template <>
struct KeyValueType<StyleKey::FontSize> {
  using value_type = float;
  static void set(StyleMap *sm, value_type value);  
};

struct StyleMap {
  std::string fontFamily = "";
  float fontSize = 14;

  template <auto key>
  void set(typename KeyValueType<std::remove_const_t<decltype(key)>>::value_type value) {
    KeyValueType<std::remove_const_t<decltype(key)>>::set(this, value);
  }

  template <typename KeyType>
  void set2(KeyType key, typename KeyValueType<KeyType>::value_type value) {
    KeyValueType<KeyType>::set(this, value);
  }
};

void KeyValueType<StyleKey::FontFamily>::set(StyleMap *sm, std::string str) {
  sm->fontFamily = str;
}
void KeyValueType<StyleKey::FontSize>::set(StyleMap *sm, float sz) {
  sm->fontSize = sz;
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/53a4d506459ff8d5)

---

Note: This approach will also work for the goal mentioned in the comment in your `main` function.  [Example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7f8121733424e21e).

Comment: Interesting, thanks. Any tips on how to get educated on this template programming topic? I see _C++ Templates: The Complete Guide_, by Vandevoorde, et al. It's 2017 so maybe not too obsolete yet.

Comment: @RobN Sadly I don't have any book recommendations I can make from personal experience.  Anything on [The Definitive C++ Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) should be pretty good, but I've not personally read any of them (I learned it all the hard way: by reading a lot of SO answers).